# Does alert('hello'); work in pageLoad() function?

Tags: javascript

Alert does not work in pageLoad, why? thanks

```
<html>
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad()
        {
            alert('hello');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body />
</html>
```

**Problem found:** Dave Ward suggests that since my page does not have a script manager (which calls PageLoad for me). that is the reason I was puzzled. I never realised I had to call it for myself when there was no script manager.

Comment: You are never calling `pageLoad()`?

Comment: pageLoad() is a function that pages with an ASP.NET ScriptManager (i.e. MicrosoftAjax.js) will automatically execute after ASP.NET AJAX's client-side library initializes and then again after every UpdatePanel refresh.  Obviously, since it's not running, he probably doesn't have a ScriptManager/MicrosoftAjax.js on his page, but that's why he might think pageLoad() would execute without being explicitly called.

Comment: @Dave Ward: very good. You have explained why on another side of the program that has ajax, that it works. I always tooks for granted the automatic call of the function. Seeing the other answers, i see i have to invoke it.

Comment: If you have jQuery available on that page, replace `pageLoad()` with `$(document).ready()`.  On the initial page load, they are almost identical.  I go into detail about that here: http://encosia.com/2009/03/25/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: @Dave Ward: Oh, i know that page very well. You are the master of that domain! Awesome, thaks for your website for all the tips I have found. (Including the wait mouse cursor for ajax).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but you need to invoke it somewhere:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad()
    {
        alert('hello');
    }

    pageLoad();  // invoke pageLoad immediately

</script>
```

Or you can delay it until all content is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad()
    {
        alert('hello');
    }

    window.onload = pageLoad;  // invoke pageLoad after all content is loaded

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

alternatively you can self invoke it

```
(function pageLoad() {
  alert('hello');
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

`pageLoad` is never being called. Try the following:

```
<html>
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad()
        {
            alert('hello');
        }
        window.onload = pageLoad;
    </script>
</head>
<body />
</html>
```

Note a better way of doing this is by using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and the following syntax:

```
$(window).load(pageLoad);
```

You could also use an alternative Javascript framework as most provide a similar way of doing this. They all take account of a number of issues related to attaching to event handlers.

Comment: On a very simple level, there is nothing wrong with the above code. However, I assume it's unlikely you actually want to run this specific code in your app. In real-life scenarios, with more complex requirements, you can quickly run into issues. For example, what if some other code in your app sets window.onload to something else? You could end up with undesirable behaviour. Using a library like jQuery to handle this for you can take care of issues like this, whilst dealing with cross-browser quirks along the way.

Comment: `window.onload = pageLoad;` removes any handler that might have been previously bound that way and `$(window).load(pageLoad);` can be used many times without conflicts. If you use `$(document).ready(pageLoad);` or just its shortut `$(pageLoad);` instead of `$(window).load(pageLoad);` then it will fire as soon as the DOM is ready without waiting for all of the resources like images to load so it is faster and much more reliable especially if you have any external resources that might load after a delay or not load at all. (Hmmm. I was answering to a comment that has just disappeared. Oh well..)

Comment: Seems like the comment the above replies were directed at has been removed. For the record, the question was why the jQuery approach is better. @rsp: spot on with the $(pageLoad) approach, this is generally the better option; I considered mentioning this though decided to keep things simple. I definitely agree with you though.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<html>
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad()
    {
        alert('hello');
    }
</script>
</head>
 <body onload="pageLoad()" />
 </html>
```