# how to include .ready() function in .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site, I am using a jquery script to make my site dynamic ( most part of the site is charged once, and while you navigates, only the main content will change). It uses .load() . Unfortunatly this function tends to negate any javascript/Jquery code that is called by the container which is dynamic. So I have to call them during the load .
Here is the code of script:

```
$(function () {

if (Modernizr.history) {

    var newHash = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function () {
        _link = $(this).attr("href");
        history.pushState(null, null, _link);
        loadContent(_link);

        return false;
    });

    function loadContent(href) {
        $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function () {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(href + " #guts", function () {

                    // I call the script here.

                        $.getScript('tablecloth/tablecloth.js', function () {
                            tablecloth();
                        });

                        $.getScript('js/domtab.js', function () {
                            domtab.init();
                        });

                        // This one is the one which doesn't work.
                        $.getScript('js/onReady.js', function () {
                        });

                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function () {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        console.log(href);
                        $("nav a[href$=" + href + "]").addClass("current");





                    });
                });
    }

    $(window).bind('popstate', function () {
        _link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); //get filename only
        loadContent(_link);


    });

} // otherwise, history is not supported, so nothing fancy here.


});
```

And I have a script for one page, that uses .click() function, onReady.js :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var maxHeight = document.getElementById("flip1").scrollHeight;
var maxHeight2 = document.getElementById("fli1A").scrollHeight;

var parent = document.getElementById("flip-container");
var DivContainerHeight = $('#text1').scrollHeight;

$("#text_var").html(maxHeight2);
//alert(DivContainerHeight);
//document.getElementById('tooltip6').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('global').style.height = DivContainerHeight + 'px';
//$("#flip-tabs").css({ height: maxHeight+'px' });
$("#flip-tabs").css({
    'height': maxHeight2 + 'px'
    //'height': '1300px'
});



$('#fl1A').on("click", function (e) {
    $("#fli1A").show();
    var maxHeight2 = document.getElementById("fli1A").scrollHeight;
    //alert("New height: " + maxHeight2);
    $("#text_var").html(maxHeight2);
    $("#flip-tabs").css({
        'height': maxHeight2 + 'px'
        //'height': '1000px'
    });
});

$('#fl1B').on("click", function (e) {
    $("#fli1B").show();
    var maxHeight2 = document.getElementById("fli1B").scrollHeight;
    //alert("New height: " + maxHeight2);
    $("#text_var").html(maxHeight2);
    $("#flip-tabs").css({
        'height': maxHeight2 + 'px'
        //'height': '1000px'
    });
});

$('#fl2A').on("click", function (e) {
    $("#fli2A").show();
    var maxHeight2 = document.getElementById("fli2A").scrollHeight;
    //alert("New height: " + maxHeight2);
    $("#text_var").html(maxHeight2);
    $("#flip-tabs").css({
        'height': maxHeight2 + 'px'
        //'height': '1000px'
    });
});

$('#fl2B').on("click", function (e) {
    $("#fli2B").show();
    var maxHeight2 = document.getElementById("fli2B").scrollHeight;
    //alert("New height: " + maxHeight2);
    $("#text_var").html(maxHeight2);
    $("#flip-tabs").css({
        'height': maxHeight2 + 'px'
        //'height': '1000px'
    });
});

$('#fl3A').on("click", function (e) {
    $("#fli3A").show();
    var maxHeight2 = document.getElementById("fli3A").scrollHeight;
    //alert("New height: " + maxHeight2);
    $("#text_var").html(maxHeight2);
    $("#flip-tabs").css({
        'height': maxHeight2 + 'px'
        //'height': '1000px'
    });
});

$('#fl3B').on("click", function (e) {
    $("#fli3B").show();
    var maxHeight2 = document.getElementById("fli3B").scrollHeight;
    //alert("New height: " + maxHeight2);
    $("#text_var").html(maxHeight2);
    $("#flip-tabs").css({
        'height': maxHeight2 + 'px'
        //'height': '1000px'
    });
});

});
```

The code will work fine when I load directly for the first time, the page where I uses this code ( A.html), but if I load another page and then go to A.html again then it won't work anymore. It is as if the getscript will work the first time I load a page. Although tablcloth() and domtab() work fine for each page.

In the head of each page I have

```
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="js/onReady.js"></script>
```

But I don't think it has any purpose.

Another question is it possible to make the script onReady load only when I load the page A.html ?

Comment: an answer to your question will probably change all of your code... you should think about the fact, that "only the main content will change". so all of your scripts are already loaded, the on handlers are already set, and also document.ready won't fire again, because it's only a part of the document that was updated. you have to use the load callback, to "update your heights" as onReady.js seems to should do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry I am not sure I understood, I think the code is already in the load callback function by using getscript. If you mean to remplace the getscript by the codes which are in onReady.js directly. I already tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution  I remplaced the codes onReady.js by this :

```
this.tabHeight = function () {

    codes......

};

window.onload = tabHeight;
```

And in the .load() I call it this way :

```
  $.getScript('js/onReady.js', function () {
             tabHeight();
  });
```

In fact I just copied the way [tablecloth](http://exerion.comule.com/tablecloth/tablecloth.js) did it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $(document).ready you could use function pageLoad(){}.

It's automatically called by the ScriptManager on a page, even on a postback.

I think that's your issue here, your changes doesn't get affected on a postback.

Hope this helps you.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer I followed the [exemples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099026/does-alerthello-work-in-pageload-function)  there and put the codes on the header of the page and tried to call the function in the header and in the changing content, but the codes would still work only the first time

Answer (score 0):

You can add events for dynamically created content in the doc ready function with jQuery's .on() method http://api.jquery.com/on/ this will prevent you from having to attach listeners on every load function call

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to remplace .click functions by `$('#..').on("click", function (e) {});` and to put them in the .ready in the header. But it did not change anything. It will be called the first time only as well.

Comment: Try calling on on the container of your dynamic content and setting your element as the target: `$('.container').on('click', '#..', function(e) {});` this will behave like delegate....should work for you